# How do I replace multiple occurences of a pattern in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, search, replace, design-patterns

Say I mave a string like,

```
%ab/c[1a]defgh[41]ijklmnop[0].qrstu[99],vwzyz
```

I want it to be displayed as,

```
%ab/c[]defgh[]ijklmnop[].qrstu[],vwzyz
```

The string can have any special characters. What I want is to replace what is inside the big brackets (there can be any number of occurance of this pattern) with empty character. The content inside the brackets can be alpha-numeric.

Your suggestion will be appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

MySQL does not have a builtin function for pattern-matching and replace.

MySQL has a [REPLACE()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/string-functions.html#function_replace) function, which makes multiple replacements in a string, but it only searches for fixed strings, not patterns.  It would very awkward to use this for the task you describe.

You'll be better off fetching the whole string back to your application, and then using a more flexible string-manipulation function on it.  For instance, [preg_replace()](https://www.php.net/preg_replace) in PHP.

Comment: Thanks Bill. Will look into that. I had been looking for something that is within MySql. But now it seems like I may have to do cross-domain work.